# Retrieve Local Storage array list using JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-storage

I want to loop through each array of my saved localstorage, but with this code

```
localStorage.setItem("fav", JSON.stringify(merchant));

                var savedMerchant = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("fav"));

                $.each(savedMerchant,function(){
                    console.log(this);

                });
```

why got this??

```
String {0: "L", length: 1, [[PrimitiveValue]]: "L"}
VM420:210 String {0: "a", length: 1, [[PrimitiveValue]]: "a"}
VM420:210 String {0: "z", length: 1, [[PrimitiveValue]]: "z"}
VM420:210 String {0: "a", length: 1, [[PrimitiveValue]]: "a"}
VM420:210 String {0: "d", length: 1, [[PrimitiveValue]]: "d"}
VM420:210 String {0: "a", length: 1, [[PrimitiveValue]]: "a"}
VM420:210 String {0: "Z", length: 1, [[PrimitiveValue]]: "Z"}
VM420:210 String {0: "a", length: 1, [[PrimitiveValue]]: "a"}
VM420:210 String {0: "l", length: 1, [[PrimitiveValue]]: "l"}
VM420:210 String {0: "o", length: 1, [[PrimitiveValue]]: "o"}
VM420:210 String {0: "r", length: 1, [[PrimitiveValue]]: "r"}
VM420:210 String {0: "a", length: 1, [[PrimitiveValue]]: "a"}
```

Comment: Can you post what did you save to the localStorage and how? It looks like a human readable representation of a JSON object.

Comment: Unless you stored a string representation of JSON object in localStorage, there's no need to JSON.parse it. As Eric, said, please edit your question with the code and data that sets the localStorage so that we can see what's going on.

Comment: You're doing your `console.log` different than your `JSON.parse`... If your console.log works, seems like you should be doing `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("fav"))`

Comment: @SethMcClaine I did.. but what's wrong now?

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

1. ensure serialization/deserialization using `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse()`
2. ensure type is array and encoded before writing to `localStorage`

---

The following statement with `JSON.parse()` implies that `localStorage["fav"]` is encoded as JSON using [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
var savedMerchant = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("fav")); 
// access to localStorage using getItem() corrected from 
// @Seth McClaine in comments to question. Good spot!
```

So ensure that type you are encoding is also an `object` using `typeof(x) === 'object'` with [x.isArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) to validate or debug before writing to `localStorage`.

Hope this helps.